# Is there any way to reverse the effects Closure Compiler (or the like) on code?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I just recently took over a project because my clients previous web dev disappeared. The only files I have to work with are what is stored on the local server. The only problem I've encountered is all of the JS has been run through Closure Compiler (or something of the like) which makes the javascript really annoying to read (at least for the bigger functions). Is there anything out there that would help me replug vars in JS so I have something cleaner to look at? I've been doing it by hand and it's getting quite tedious.

Here's an example of what I'm dealing with:

```
    var n = {},
        e = a.extend(n, x),
        y = "pageLoaded",
        u = "pageLoading",
        c = "modLoaded",
        w = "xhrComplete",
        l = true,
        v = false,
        s = a("body"),
        g = Modernizr.historymanagement,
        f = "",
        t = "",
        r = "",
        k = null,
        b = window.History;
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Tre

Comment: If it is compiled with ADVANCED MODE, I don't think you can.  The Closure Compiler's Advanced Mode transformation is one-way.  The mapping is not one-one or onto, so you cannot get back to the original source.  The compiled JavaScript is heavily optimized and rewritten to be extremely efficient.  However, if the code is merely minified via SIMPLE MODE, then you can do with simple replacement of variable names.  Judging from your code, it is probably SIMPLE MODE, because otherwise the "extend" function under "a" will be renamed.

Comment: And it doesn't "smell" like output from the Closure Compiler.  It may be packed with some other minifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's munged. To a certain degree you can replace tokens when literals are assigned - you could, for example, replace all instances of `l` with `true` and `v` with `false` in the code. But there are other things which it does that would be a lot more complex to reverse and I don't believe anyone's put much effort into it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there was a term for this. Thanks for the heads up. But, I figured as much. I've been plugging vars into stuff as I need, just so I don't get lost. It really is quite annoying.

Comment: Working with obfuscated and munged code is hard. Reversing it is painful. Replacement of the variables with their respective literals is probably the easiest thing to do and shouldn't take long (it could be done with a JavaScript tokeniser, or to a more patchy degree with simple regular expressions, but I'm not aware of any utilities to do it - I've never looked much, though, there may be). Then also refactor it further to use meaningful variable names.

Comment: Are there any tools you would recommend? Something with real refactoring Support?

Comment: Not for JavaScript. I'm above refactoring tools, anyway. I Use Vim. ;-)